# Windows 10 Lenovo U410 Reset boot loop

Tags: boot, windows-10, lenovo-laptop, reset, infinite-loop

I have a Lenovo U410 that was running slowly so I decided to do a full system reset using the built in application in Windows 10. I started it and left, when I returned there was an error message with the only option to cancel the reset. Now it is stuck in a boot loop with the Lenovo logo popping up repeatedly and nothing else happened. I have checked the boot options in the BIOS and it is set on Legacy. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to boot into Windows safe mode by holding `F8` after the Lenovo logo? What did the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the computer fail to find the OS during the startup.

Please download the installation media here

Windows 10 Tech Bench Upgrade Program
[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench](https://web.archive.org/web/20160720221451/http://www.microsoft.com:80/en-us/software-download/techbench)

Boot from the media and choose Repair the computer, then in advanced option, choose command prompt, then run commands below to repair Boot configuration data:

bootrec /fixmbr

bootrec /fixboot

bootrec /scanos

bootrec /rebuildbcd

If still not work,  try the repair upgrade again to fix this issue:

How to perform a repair upgrade.
[http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085)